# Напишите функцию f15, которая вначале проверяет, есть ли элемент из i-15 в массиве d15 а потом - если нет - добавляет его в массив

Tags: javascript

https://codepen.io/Tester2004-07/pen/MWwvoja

```
let d15 = [0, 2, 5, -4, 6, 22, -9, -12, 8, 12, 13, 78];

function f15() {
    let inp = +document.querySelector('.i-15').value;

    if( d15.indexOf(inp != -1) ) {
        console.log(1);    
    }
    else {
        d15.push(inp);
    }
}

document.querySelector('.b-15').onclick = f15;
```

Comment: Скобка не там в условии. Ну и вообще, проще использовать `includes` вместо `indexOf`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    let d15 = [0, 2, 5, -4, 6, 22, -9, -12, 8, 12, 13, 78];

    function f15() {
        let inp = document.querySelector('.i-15').value;

        if(d15.indexOf(+inp) != -1){
            console.log('Есть элемент в массиве');
        }
        else{
            d15.push(+inp);
            console.log(d15);
        }
    }
    document.querySelector('.b-15').onclick = f15;
```

```html
<input class="i-15">
<button class="b-15">Тык</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let d15 = [0, 2, 5, -4, 6, 22, -9, -12, 8, 12, 13, 78];

function f15() {
let inp = +document.querySelector('.i-15').value;
        if (d15.indexOf(inp) == -1) {
            d15.push(inp);
        }
    showArr('.out-15', d15);
}

document.querySelector('.b-15').onclick = f15;
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
let d15 = [0, 2, 5, -4, 6, 22, -9, -12, 8, 12, 13, 78];
let input = document.querySelector(".i-15");
function f15() {
  let inpValueNumber = Number.parseInt(input.value);
  for (let i = 0; i < d15.length; i++) {
    if (inpValueNumber !== d15[i]) d15.push(inpValueNumber);
    break;
  }

  showArr(".out-15", d15);
}

document.querySelector(".b-15").onclick = f15;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]